# Insetting the outside of a bend

Tags: modeling, mesh

I can't get the outside of a bend to inset, I have almost everything inset 0.5cm and lowered 0.5cm to create embossed effect on the model, but this last piece just won't select like it should and I can't get it to inset to finish the embossed look(it's a dagger). Please refer to the screenshots provided.
I am quite the novice in Blender and I do this to train/ enhance my skills in 3D modeling.

How do I get this to work?

*EDIT: I am trying to inset the last part so I can achieve the embossed effect just like the rest (see screenshot 3), you can see in this picture that I still need to deepen that last part of the inside of the blade, I used the inset tool to do the rest of the inside of the blade but when I try to select the edges of this last part where you have this weird bend on the inside of the pattern, then it won't select the outside of the pattern but only the inside, that way I can't use the inset tool to deepen this inside part and thus I cannot finish this project. Do you have any idea how I can deepen that part?
[image: Intersect problem 1]

[image: Intersect Problem 2]

[image: Intersect problem 3]

Comment: "I cant get the outside of a bend to intersect" - it is not clear what you mean by this. What's "outside of a bend"? What should it intersect with? What are you trying to achieve here? You should edit the question and clarify in detail. I don't think it is possible to answer it as it is now.

Comment: I have edited the question, i hope i have specified it enough.

Comment: To be honest I still have little idea, how you are trying to model this, and what "intersect tool" you are talking about. There is no intersect tool in Blender as far as I know if we are talking about tools in the tool panel, there is Intersect(Knife) operator that could probably be called intersect tool, but I don't understand how you would use this and you also don't need selection for it... There is  also intersect mode for Boolean modifiers and some functions containing "intersect" in their names in some addons like Bool Tool, but your screenshots don't seem to be related to that.

Comment: sorry i use the I shortcut for this, i found a video that called this intersect er something *EDIT: sorry pardon me i have misunderstood this, I use the inset tool

Comment: Well, you only select faces and hit i to use inset operator and the Inset Tool(that's in the Tool Panel on the left of your 3d Viewport, the one that toggles with t while in viewport) is also pretty intuitive. What are you struggling with? Maybe you are selecting edges? You need faces for that. I cannot think of anything else that might go wrong. Maybe you could explain in detail how you are trying to use it.

Comment: Hi yes, the simple way is I select the edges, which does not give the intended results, problem is I don't know how to select faces in specific, is there a shortkey for this?

Comment: The first step to select faces is either press the button for the _Face Select_ mode at the top of the _3D Viewport_ when you are in _Edit Mode_ or press `3` to switch the mode (`1` is _Vertex Select_, `2` is _Edge Select_). A face is also selected automatically when all its bounding edges or all corner vertices are selected, but usually _Face Select_ mode is easier if you don't need to select individual edges or vertices.

Comment: yes it all worked out great, model is now finished, thank you all for the advise :)